# Laravel 8 View Component

Tags: php, laravel

Its correct, if I make menu component with blade view component and get query from it?

Or I need use some controller for that?

**View/Components/Menus/Main.php**

```
namespace App\View\Components\Menus;

use App\Models\MenuItem;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Main extends Component
{
    public $items;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = Cache::remember('mainMenuItems', 86000, function () {
            return MenuItem::whereMenuTypeId(1)->get();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.menus.main');
    }
}
```

**resources/views/includes/header.blade.php**

```
<header class="flex items-center pt-16 pb-10">
    <div class="w-3/12">
        <a href="/">
            <img src="{{ asset('/assets/images/logo.png') }}">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-9/12">
        <x-menus.main/>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Hello, are you asking if the approach itself is correct or do you have an issue that you need help with?

Comment: Its works, but I but I'm not sure if this is correct way

Comment: Ah okay, it may be better placed in the Code Review overflow as that's designed to discuss best practice more. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dean, the question will need some work before it would be [ready for Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).